# Jquery Ajax with ruby on rails (show loading message on a div)

Tags: jquery

I need to show a message as loading until the data gets returned and updates in my div.. How do I do it.. I could update the data on complete..

<%= javascript_tag do %>
        jQuery(function($) 
        {
            $("#calendar_tab").click(function()
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url:'/calendar/showcal/<%=@space.id%>',
                    type:'GET',
                    dataType:'script',
                    data:{month:'9'},

```
                complete: function(data)
                {

                }

            });
        });

    });
```

<% end %>

Answer (score 1):

You can use beforeSend callback to initiate the loading.... statement or any other animation and can dismiss it on complete callback function.

```
<%= javascript_tag do %> 
  jQuery(function($) {
    $("#calendar_tab").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url:'/calendar/showcal/<%=@space.id%>',
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'script',
        data:{month:'9'},
        **beforeSend: function() { 
        },**
        complete: function(data) {
        }
     });
  });
});
<% end %>
```